# For a menu custom link (without a link) a "#" is appended. Can this just be blank, i.e. NO link?

Tags: menus

In the WordPress menu there are Custom Links which allow for the insertion of any link you want.

But, I do not want any link there at all.

I am referring to this:

[image]

If I leave it blank then WordPress appends a "#" which when clicked pushes the user to the top of the page. Is there anyway to remove this or make the link do nothing as opposed to sending user to the top of the page?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

The answer is `#!` within the URL